# Answer this questionnaire for five US cents?

Tags: discussion

I guess I can't complain that people are mining SO for eminent contributors such as myself, as in the below mail I recently received:

---

giasresearchopinerfive@gmail.com 
11:29 PM (50 minutes ago)

Dear torazaburo,

We are conducting a research on the implications of the reviews about APIs in developer forums 
and how such opinions shape your overall decisions on the selection and usage of APIs. 
One of the participants will be randomly selected for a $50 USD Amazon gift card.

We found that you have been an influential contributor in Stack Overflow questions and answers (reputation: 50658). 
We would very much appreciate your inputs to our study. This survey is used to evaluate 
my PhD resarch. I am a senior PhD candidate at McGill University, Montreal, Canada.

The survey is not used for any commercial endeavors by any means. Your inputs will help tremendously and greatly appreciated!

The survey will only take 20-25 minutes for you to complete. All the responses will be anonymized. 
The survey is governed by Ethics approval from McGill University 
and thus we are bound by law to ensure your privacy.

The survey is available here (Link opens a Google form): [Needs for API reviews to support development tasks](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeyeL4nxhs8MSQQL-556XdB65SesIqMM_B1e_ldNegSH2E5Bw/viewform?c=0&w=1)

We thank you very much for your participation!

Sincerely,

Gias Uddin, PhD candidate at the School of Computer Science of McGill University, Montréal, Canada
Prof. Olga Baysal, Assistant professor, School of Computer Science of Carleton University, Canada
Prof. Latifa Guerrouj, Assistant professor, École de Technologie Supérieure, Montréal, Canada
Prof. Foutse Khomh, Associate Professor, Ecole Polytechnique Montreal, Montréal, Canada

Contact emails: Gias (gias@cs.mcgill.ca), Olga (olga.baysal@carleton.ca), Latifa (latifa.guerrouj@etsmtl.ca), Foutse (foutse.khomh@polymtl.ca).

---

Assuming they sent this to 1,000 people, and one of these will receive the Amazon gift card, the expected value is five cents. If the survey takes 30 minutes to complete, that comes out to ten cents per hour. I'm used to being underpaid, but this is ridiculous.

No, there's no question here (other than maybe, it is OK for them mine the SO database and send out mails like this, right?).

Random questions:

1. If (s)he's a "senior PhD candidate", are there also "junior PhD candidates"? What's the difference?
2. Is (s)he "conducting research", as stated at the beginning. or is my answer going to be used to "**evaluate** his/her PhD research", as it says later?
3. They say my answers are going to be used to understand my "overall decisions on the selection and usage of APIs". I wonder if they understand that I don't really have a choice of APIs. If I want to use Google maps, I use their APIs. If I want to get Github info, I use their APIs.
4. Shouldn't a PhD candidate know how to spell, or failing that, know how to use a spell-checker, so they don't say "resarch"?

Comment: Realistically speaking, the only way they'd have gotten in touch with you is if you have some email address that they can use to identify you - either through Twitter, LinkedIn, or on your own website.  The chances are virtually nil that Stack Overflow has released this information themselves.  All other comments are best directed at the people actually doing the study; if they respond verifying that they did actually send this email out then you can work out how they got your contact details in the first place.

Comment: Am I the only one to accidentally read "Sear Chopin" in the email string?

Comment: You can spend 30 minutes earning imaginary super rainbow unicorn points or 5 cents, the choice is yours ;)

Comment: Maybe they want to train their algorithms: http://swat.polymtl.ca/data/opinionvalue-technical-report.pdf